# TZupdater failing with tzdata2016g release

Tags: java, timezone, java-time, timezone-offset

TZUpdater 2.1.0 is failing with tzdata2016g release. For Java 8 it fails with "Source directory does not contain file: VERSION" error, while it completes with "JRE updated to version : tzdataunknown" comment for Java 7.

The reason of this seems to be recent change of IANA tzdata distribution: Unsetting VERSION field of Makefile. There is a bug reported regarding the issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8166928.

DST date(30th October 2016) is getting closer and we at least need a workaround for this. Is it, somehow, possible?

Answer (score 14):

Workaround:

- Update `Makefile` of http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/releases/tzdata2016g.tar.gz: Original value of `VERSION` variable is `unknown` and you need to update it to `2016g`.
- Regenerate `tzdata2016g.tar.gz.sha512` file

Edit 1: Modified(working) files can be downloaded from [tzupdater_2016g_workaround](https://github.com/kumlali/tzupdater_2016g_workaround)

Edit 2: Oracle announced the same workaround: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html#issues. However you still need to create working `tzdata2016g.tar.gz` and `tzdata2016g.tar.gz.sha512` files by yourself. You instead can download the files I prepared. See Edit 1.

Comment: I have done this workaround for tzdata2016h. But tzupdater would complain about `JRE has later version (tzdataunknown) than the tzupdater provided one (tzdata2016h)` So i forced update using `-f` option which worked fine.

Answer (score 8):

oneliner for the lazy ones:

```
 curl https://github.com/anlcan/tzupdate/raw/master/tzupdate.zip -o tzup.zip && unzip tzup.zip && cd tzup && sh run.sh
```

tzupdate.zip file contains the `tzdata2016g.tar.gz`, the correct hash `tzdata2016g.tar.gz.sha512` and the script with the java tzupdate command. You can find the zip file here: https://github.com/anlcan/tzupdate .

Comment: Please use English on StackOverflow.  Also, your answer is just to download some zip file you made and blindly run it?  That's not a very safe practice, and not a good descriptive answer for StackOverflow.